# Mod rewrite all files to public folder AND strip .php, .html if file exists

Tags: php, html, azure, web-config

1) I'm trying to deploy to an Azure web app. I'm trying to write all traffic from wwwdata to wwwdata/app/public/ so I can keep sensitive files safe.

2) I also want pretty URLs by removing the .php, or .html if the file exists.

I can achieve both of the above functionalities individually but get problems trying to implement both simutaniously. I've tried as one file defining the full ruleset and have also tried seperating in to two as so...

```
/web.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="TransferToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="app/public/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

with

```
/app/public/web.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite html" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But always recieve...

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, in the first rule, you have specified stopProcessing="true", thus the second rule is not processed. I wonder have you tried to set it as false or remove the stopProcessing property to see if it works fine? I have a quick test on Azure website:  http://testgitproject.azurewebsites.net/example1 & http://testgitproject.azurewebsites.net/example2 and it seems working as expected. Should you have any further concern or if I have any misunderstood on your issue, please feel free to let me know.